# What are the "accents" called in Mathematics?

Tags: notation

For instance, an x with a line over it representing the mean value. What are these "accents" called when they are mathematical and where can I find a good list of them?

Sorry if this is a really basic question.

Comment: $\overline{x}$ is "x bar".

Comment: I doubt there is a universal term.  https://abstractmath.org/MM/MMOtherSymbols.htm calls these accents.  Typographers might call them combining diacritical marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the meaning depends of the theory. A list of them in latex documentation for example https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Manual_de_LaTeX/Textos_t%C3%A9cnicos/Matem%C3%A1ticas/Acentuaci%C3%B3n_en_modo_matem%C3%A1tico

(that page in spanish, but you can find in english too)